# Spring boot activemq overriding the connection factory

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am new to Spring boot and i am trying to lookup my own connection factory instead of using the default 'ConnectionFactory' which Spring boot provides and also trying to lookup the already defined queue without using dynamicqueues.

How can i do that?
    Should i add jndi.properties file and add it there so i can lookup?

Can someone suggest?

Comment: you want to use jndi or spring bean ? can you post your code. you can override spring default 'ConnectionFactory' by creating a method with the same name

Comment: can you please give an example? I want to override it in Spring-boot application

Answer (score 1):

> The Spring Integration configuration by default is looking for a
> Spring Bean called ‘connectionFactory’.
>
> Spring Boot by default,
> creates the JMS connection factory using the name
> ‘jmsConnectionFactory’.

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration.java